# ".NET" and "OCaml" formatting of signatures

Tags: f#

F# allows ".NET" and "OCaml" formatting of signatures. This can be confusing when you fall into the habit of using one style, and then find a situation where you cannot properly format the signature you need. Consider this code, which requires a flexible type as the output of the function input to foo:

```
let foo n (bar: int -> #seq<'a>) =
    (fun () -> Vector.ofSeq (bar n))

let foobar n = Array.ofSeq([1..n])

let x = foo 10 foobar
```

I could not figure out how to express #seq<'a> in OCaml format. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following compiles just fine:

```
type A<'a>(x) =
    member __.Get : 'a = x
    abstract PairWith : 'b -> ('a * 'b * int)
    default __.PairWith y = x, y, 1

type B<'a>(x) =
    inherit A<'a>(x)
    override __.PairWith y = x, y, 2

let pairAB (x : #A<'a>) y =
    x, x.PairWith y

type 'a X (x) =
    member __.Get : 'a = x
    abstract PairWith : 'b -> ('a * 'b * int)
    default __.PairWith y = x, y, 1

type 'a Y (x) =
    inherit X<'a>(x)
    override __.PairWith y = x, y, 2

let pairXY (x : #('a X)) y =
    x, x.PairWith y
```

So you can guess (and then confirm with F# Interactive) that you are looking for `#('a seq)`.

Comment: Perfect. I'm not sure what the F# team intended by allowing two styles of signature. There must be some advantage. I know I inadvertently mix the styles, which only looks confusing.

Comment: @Jack The OCaml style is there for backwards-compatibility, the .Net style is because F# is on the .Net (and thus should use its styles and conventions, when possible).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I assume that you want to put the type variable in front of the type name, e.g. `'a #seq`.

According to the language specification (§5.1.5) it's not possible since:

> A type of the form `#type` is an anonymous type with a subtype constraint and is equivalent to `'a when 'a :> type`, where `'a` is a fresh type inference variable.

So you could write your type like: `'a when 'a :> seq<'b>`.

EDIT: You could actually use `#('a seq)`, but it looks awkward and I doubt it's what you want.

EDIT2: Didn't see Ramon Snir's answer :).